# Change Python path in CDH for pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-cdh

I need to change the python that is being used with my CDH5.5.1 cluster. My research pointed me to set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` in spark-env.sh. I tried that manually without success. I then used Cloudera Manager to set the variable in both the 'Spark Service Environment Advanced Configuration Snippet'  and  'Spark Service Advanced Configuration Snippet' & about everywhere else that referenced spark-env-sh. This hasn't worked and I'm at a lost where to go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the PYSPARK_PYTHON variable to the YARN configuration :
`YARN (MR2 Included) Service Environment Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve)`
Do that, restart the cluster and you are good to go.